# how to test webrtc aec in android?

Tags: android, webrtc, speex, stagefright, aec

Hi i want to test the webrtc aec and i want  to know how it  works..
Because i am going to integrate  speex.
I dont know how to do all the things but i have to do.
So please give me the information about how to test and is there any application to test the webrtc.
I have to test in android environment and have to integrate in the native code.

I tried skype and line and other voip apps but i didnt get any logs regarding the webrtc aec.

Comment: If you hear yourself, AEC failed, if you do not, then AEC succeeded. Test over... :)

Comment: Can u please explain me how can i test? Through which application can i test???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webRTC` sources can be found in AOSP site under [`/external/webrtc`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/external/webrtc/). The **AEC** specific modules are available in the [`audio_processing`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/external/webrtc/src/modules/audio_processing/) folder.

An unit test program for audio only is also available under the [tests](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/external/webrtc/src/modules/audio_processing/test/process_test.cc) folder. Please check the [`--aec` option](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/external/webrtc/src/modules/audio_processing/test/process_test.cc#96).

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you explain me somewhat clearly please. what is --aec option